# Xcode Memory Utilized

Tags: xcode, memory, restkit

So in xcode, the Debug Navigator shows CPU Usage and Memory usage.  When you click on Memory it says 'Memory Utilized'.

In my app I am using the latest Restkit (0.20.x) and every time I make a GET request using getObjectsAtPath (which doesn't even return a very large payload), the memory utilized increases about 2mb.  So if I refresh my app 100 times, the Memory Utilized will have grown over 200mb.

However, when I run the Leaks tool, the Live Bytes remain fairly small and do not increase with each new request.  Live bytes remains below 10mb the whole time.

So do I have a memory issue or not?  Memory Utilized grows like crazy, but Live Bytes suggests everything is okay.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Heapshot Analysis](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) to evaluate the situation. If that shows no growth, then the memory consumption may be virtual memory which may (for example) reside in a cache/store which may support eviction and recreation -- so you should also identify growth in Virtual Memory regions.

If you keep making requests (e.g. try 200 refreshes), the memory will likely decrease at some point - or you will have memory warnings and ultimately allocation requests may fail. Determine how memory is reduced, if this is the case. Otherwise, you will need to determine where it is created and possibly referenced.

Also, test on a device in this case. The simulator is able to utilise much more memory than a device simply because it has more to work with. Memory constraints are not simulated.

Comment: The question begs an answer to what is being displayed.

Comment: @Zaph right, but the OP needs to know how to dig deeper and where to look to get that information. i could attempt to repro the problem over here but i just don't consider that a good Q/A effort ratio.